# Why a key is ignored and the same value is assigned to every item of a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a question about how to use a key in a python dictionary.

I have a detector setup, which I represent with a nested dictionary. The detector consists of 3 sub-arrays, each sub-array consists of 5 rows and each row contains 48 pixels. Every pixel has a x-y coordinates and intensity.
So, I represented this structure as following:

```
def pixel_grid(self):
    
    # create a tree-like structure to access every pixel :

    # every pixel has the following components
    pixel = {'coord_x' : [], 'coord_y' : [], 'intensity' : None}

    # create an index to access each pixel 'p1'-'p48'
    pix_ind = ['p'+str(i) for i in range(1,49)]

    # create a row index : 'row1'-'row5'
    pix_arrays = ['row'+str(i) for i in range(1,6)]

    # create a sub-array, which consist of 5 rows with 48 pixels per row
    sub = { name:{ key: pixel for key in pix_ind} for name in pix_arrays}

    # create a detector with 3 sub-arrays 
    self.detector = {'sub1' : sub,
                     'sub2' : sub,
                     'sub3' : sub}

    # assign coordinates to each pixel: 
    # begin with a middle sub-array, middle row, middle pixel
    pix_width = 1.294
    begin_x = 0
    end_x = pix_width
    self.detector['sub2']['row3']['p25']['coord_x'] = [begin_x, end_x]

   
    '''
    The following loop would be used to assign coords to other pixels, 
    but currently is used to check the x-coord of the pixels
     '''
    for i, p in enumerate(self.detector['sub2']['row3'].keys()):
        print(p, ':', self.detector['sub2']['row3'][p]['coord_x'])
   
    return None
```

However, when I print the `x_coord`, it seems that the coordinates of pixel `p25` were assigned to every pixel! This is a result of the printing:

```
p1 : [0, 1.294]
p2 : [0, 1.294]
p3 : [0, 1.294]
p4 : [0, 1.294]
...
...
p45 : [0, 1.294]
p46 : [0, 1.294]
p47 : [0, 1.294]
p48 : [0, 1.294]
```

I don't understand why it happened. I was expecting an empty `coord_x` list for all pixels except of `p25`, which is indeed `[0, 1.294]`. What did I do wrong? How can I get an output such that:

```
p1 :  []
p2 :  []
...
...
p24 : []
p25 : [0, 1.294]
p26 : []
...
...
p48 : []
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You seem to be expecting more "value-oriented" than "reference-oriented" behavior, with a lot of implicit copies. Python almost never implicitly copies objects. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to same lists.

Try:

```
from copy import deepcopy

sub = { name:{ key: deepcopy(pixel) for key in pix_ind} for name in pix_arrays}

self.detector = {'sub1' : deepcopy(sub),
                 'sub2' : deepcopy(sub),
                 'sub3' : deepcopy(sub)}
```

Comment: There's more aliasing going on than just that - for example, the triple `sub` in the initialization of `self.detector`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, thank you for your reply, but I think I need this triple initiation because each of the `sub`'s would contain different `coord_x`, `coord_y` and `intensity`. Or did I not understand what you meant?

Comment: @astrodi: "because each of the sub's would contain different coord_x, coord_y and intensity" - but they wouldn't. You've created 3 references to one object. You can't have each of the `sub`s contain different data, because there's only one `sub`!

Comment: @astrodi check now

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: Ooh, I get it! I would have to create `sub1` - `sub3` instead of `sub`. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @vks : Muchas gracias! ;)